# Trying to update user on Azure B2C gives me an "Insufficient Privileges" error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using B2C and MS Graph API to create new users in B2C, however when I try and update a user, using the update command below:

```
                    await _graphClient.Users[b2cUser.Id]
                    .Request()
                    .UpdateAsync(CreateGraphUserForUpdateCreate(extensionInstance, user));
```

I get the error:

```
    Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 6494a468-e7e2-41ed-a39c-527715656737
    date: 2020-04-23T11:14:13
```

I have given my App Directory.Read.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All API permissions.

Is there another permission I need to set?

**UPDATE**
 The code to create the authProvider is as below (without a user approach):

```
    // Initialize the client credential auth provider
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(config.AppId)
        .WithTenantId(config.Tenant)
        .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

    // Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
    _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

And screen shot of permissions:

[image]

Comment: Which kind of permissions are you using? Delegated permissions or Application permissions? And please provide a screenshot of your API permissions assigned in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Update user Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions):

If you implement [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user), you should add one of the Delegated permissions:

```
User.ReadWrite, User.ReadWrite.All, User.ManageIdentities.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All
```

[image]

And you should use [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) to get the `authProvider`.

If you implement [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), you should add one of the Application permissions:

```
User.ReadWrite.All, User.ManageIdentities.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

[image]

And you should use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to get the `authProvider`.

Please **note** that after you add the permissions in Azure AD app, don't forget to click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}".

[image]

---

**Update:**

You are trying to update the password. When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following permission is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, which you haven't added into your Azure AD app. That's why this error occurs. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've updated the original post with the extra details. In my case this is a backend service making changes so I'm using the ClientCredentialProvider. I'm not sure why I get the error when updating a user, but not when reading/creating the user in the first place.

Comment: @Slicc Can you share code of `CreateGraphUserForUpdateCreate(extensionInstance, user)`? Which properties are you trying to update?

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, it's because I was trying to change the password, which I didn't actually want to do. Thanks for your suggestion of checking the properties!!

Comment: @Slicc Thanks for your reply. I'll update the answer based on our discussion.